# Regular expression to match Excel Formula

Tags: excel

In one of my problems to solve, I do have to substitute my range values in an Excel Formula with their equivalent cell references, i.e., for example, if I have an Excel Formula:

= Sum(F10:F14)

I have to replace it with:

= Sum(F10,F11,F12,F13,F14).

I am trying to match the regular expressions which helps me find

1. if an Excel Formula has been defined with a pattern which includes: 'Sum' and a ':'
2. To extract the cells which are included in the range, as in F10:F14

Somehow, I am stuck at Point 1 :-)

For, this I created the following pattern:

```
Regex formulaMatcher = new Regex(@"=*SUM\([\w]*[\w,]*[\w]+:[\w]+[\w]*[\w,]*\)*");
foreach (Match m in formulaMatcher.Matches("=SUM(F55,F151:F159)"))
    m.Value.Dump();
```

Now, the above pattern is working perfectly for the formulas:

```
        // =SUM(F15,F25,F31:F35)
        // =SUM(F10:F12,F26,F31)
        // =SUM(F45,F55,F61:F63,F40)
        // =F14-SUM(F16:F17)
        // =SUM(F35:F37)
        // =SUM(F10:F13)-F11
        // =SUM(F27:F29)/3
        // =F19-F21+SUM(F22:F23)
        // =ROUND(F43-SUM(F23:F42),2)
        // =SUM(F174:F178)+F134+F120+F97
```

But it is failing for: SUM(F81:F89,F105:F113,F128:F135), i.e., for cases involving multiple range operators within the formula

Please assist me in finding out how I could achieve the above result?

Cheers,
Anil

Comment: I presume this is homeowork - else it is a very strange question

Answer (score 1):

At first, I'd suggest using a simpler regex, like:

```
Regex formulaMatcher = new Regex(@"=*SUM\(.*?[\w]+:[\w]+.*?\)*");
```

(I don't know if excel supports non-greedy quantifiers, if it doesn't, use `*` instead of `*?`, will work also - but less efficient)

This will also match `SUM` with **any** contents besides intervals, which may or may not be what you want. If it **must** be justs cells or intervals, the regex will become a lot more complicated, but it's doable: you just have to break it down to those two simple cases or'ed together:

- one interval, zero or more intervals or cells starting with comma;

  - `\w+:\w+(,\w+(:\w+)?)*`
- one cell, zero or more cells starting with comma, an interval starting with comma, zero or more intervals or cells starting with comma).

  - `\w+(,\w+)*,\w+:\w+(,\w+(:\w+)?)*`

**Edit:** Nevermind that, you can simplify it to:

- zero or more cells ending with comma

  - `(\w+,)*`
- one interval

  - `\w+:\w+`
- zero or more cells or intervals starting with comma

  - `(,\w+(:\w+)?)*`

Result:

```
Regex formulaMatcher = new Regex(@"=*SUM\((\w+,)*\w+:\w+(,\w+(:\w+)?)*\)*");
```

P.S. I'm unsure whether or not you have to escape commans or colons.

Answer (score 1):

Excel lets you have blocks of cells and single cells, stemming for @mgibsonbr 's answer I can up with :

```
^=SUM\((\w+\d+)((:\w+\d+)|(,\w+\w+)*)((,\w+\d)((:\w+\d+)|(,\w+\w+)*))*\)$
```

This also makes sure you only have two cells for a range...ie. not a2:a3:a4